# text and buttons gets overlayed.....i want the buttons fixed at the bottom of the textview

Tags: java, android, html

[image]
I have uploaded a screenshot of the problem please check...
the text in the textview and the buttons gets over each other. I have used html for the text and scrollbar for it.....Please Help!!!!

Here's my code:

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/images"
tools:context="com.example.acer.aartisangrah.alaganraya">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="decrease"
    android:text="Decrease" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="increase"
    android:text="Increase" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here for the Text View I have used HTML

CODE:

```
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
tv.setTextSize((float) 18.0);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.five)));
```

please note that the textsize of text in the text view can be increased or decreased....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your code like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/images"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.acer.aartisangrah.alaganraya">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="decrease"
        android:text="Decrease" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="increase"
        android:text="Increase" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just copy and paste the the code I write and see is that work ?

Comment: Make scrollview wrape content

Comment: its still the same with your code also.....this is with increasing the font size....

Comment: Try one more thing. Make relative layout to linearlayout. Give scrollview height 0dp and and give weight to 1. Wrape both button in another layout like linearlayout then see

Comment: could you please do the needful changes in the comment code....because after adding the linear layout the buttons have gone up....please

Comment: Okay u r there. Just make scroll view up and whole button layout down. If  not work then I update whole code

Comment: it says height cannot be zero.....and the buttons have moved to right from left but still it is at top....

Comment: Error for the layout_height="0"                                                  Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, probably intended for layout_width less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Using 0dp as the width in a horizontal LinearLayout with weights is a useful trick to ensure that only the weights (and not the intrinsic sizes) are used when sizing the children.  However, if you use 0dp for the opposite dimension, the view will be invisible. This can happen if you change the orientation of a layout without also flipping the 0dp dimension in all the children

Comment: try the one i edit. copy whole and replace your whole code for now.

Comment: Bdw why the layout_height="wrap_content takes the full screen and take my buttons on top???

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have not specified the alignment order for your views.

Eg : You can use `android:layout_above="@+id/btn"` or `android:layout_below="@+id/scrollbar` for arranging views.

Comment: Put both these buttons in a LinearLayout/RelativeLayout (name id as btnLayout). Add `android:layout_above="@+id/btnLayout` to the scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Just add these in your layout -

```
<ScrollView...
    android:id=@+id/scroll_view>

...

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_below=@id/scroll_view
     .../>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_below=@id/scroll_view
    android:layout_toRightof=@id/b1
    .../>
```